# How to get port forwarding to work with gatsby and vagrant or virtualbox

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vagrant, virtualbox, gatsby

When using [Gatsby](https://www.gatsbyjs.org) running on Vagrant (over Virtualbox) I cannot get the port forwarding to work.

Gatsby by default runs on localhost port 8000.

My Vagrantfile seems to forward the correct ports using the following:

```
config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 8000, host: 8000
```

When I start Gatsby on the Vagrant box using `yarn develop`, everything looks ok on the guest box and the app is running on localhost:8000

```
info bootstrap finished - 7.354 s

 DONE  Compiled successfully in 9091ms                                                                                                                                                                                                

You can now view foo-bar-org in the browser.

  http://localhost:8000/
```

I can run `curl http://localhost:8000` on the guest box to verify that it is indeed serving up content locally.

Back over on the host box when I go into the browser and try to access http://localhost:8000 it says "Localhost refused to connect".

Running `netstat -tulnp | grep 8000` on the guest box I get the following:

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1909/node
```

And running the same on the host box I get this output:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8000            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      13827/VBoxHeadless
```

Answer (score 9):

I did get this working by changing the way I run Gatsby on the guest box. It seems like `gatsby develop -H 0.0.0.0` will get Gatsby listening on connections from all hosts. The `netstat -tulnp | grep 8000` output then changes to:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8000            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2348/node
```

I'm answering my own question in case it helps someone else, but if someone can come up with a better way of doing this with Gatsby still listening just on localhost then I would prefer that answer and will accept that answer.

Comment: I had this same issue and this answer totally worked for me. Thanks!